# How to wait for PlayerPrefs.SetString to be saved on disk?

Tags: unity-game-engine, coroutine

In my recent published mobile game I have implemented an online leaderboard. Some users ran into issues on registration process. In short words the registration is coded like this:

```
    // coroutine
    DownloadLeaderBoard () {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (PlayerPrefs.GetString ("USERNAME"))) {
            RegisterUser();
            yield break;
        }
        // Download and display Leaderboard
    }

    // coroutine
    RegisterUser () {
        // user has entered a valid username
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("USERNAME" username);
        DownloadLeaderboard();
    }
```

So after I saved the username, I have to make sure that it's on the disk **before** I call DownloadLeaderboard() again! How can I achieve that and prevent that RegisterUser() is called multiple times?

Comment: Avoid asking the-same question twice. All you had to do was add your code to your old question. No need for duplicates.

Comment: Since the issue and the question is a littlebit different, I thought I ask this seperate.

Comment: They are the-same issue. I think you should delete one.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("USERNAME")) {
    // dont't register user again
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.